# Python: Find difference between two dictionaries containing lists

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, dictionary

I have two dictionaries that have the following structure:

```
a = {'joe': [24,32,422], 'bob': [1,42,32,24], 'jack':[0,3,222]}
b = {'joe': [24], 'bob': [1,42,32]}
```

I would like to retrieve the difference between these two dictionaries which in this case would result as:

```
{'joe': [32,422], 'bob': [24], 'jack':[0,3,222]}
```

I know that I could do this with a messy loop, but I would like to know how can I achieve this in a clean, pythonic fashion?

I did try: `a.items() - b.items()`

but I get the following error: `unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'dict_values' and 'dict_values'`

Thanks for your help

Comment: I would like to point out that the answers using sets which are casted back to lists will destroy the order of the lists (if the order is not changed for a specific example, that's a coincidence). Since your specifications don't say that the order of the lists is unimportant, I think this fact should be noted.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Assuming that there would be no duplicate entries in any of your lists, you can do what you want with `set`s but not with lists:

```
>>> a = {'joe': [24,32,422], 'bob': [1,42,32,24], 'jack':[0,3,222]}
>>> b = {'joe': [24], 'bob': [1,42,32]}
>>> {key: list(set(a[key])- set(b.get(key,[]))) for key in a}
{'joe': [32, 422], 'bob': [24], 'jack': [0, 3, 222]}
```

Note two things:

- I convert the set back to a list when I set it as the value
- I use `b.get` rather than `b[key]` to handle if the key does not exist in `b`, but does in `a`

EDIT - using a for loop:

I realized that the comprehension may not be that self explanatory so this is an equivalent bit of code using a for loop:

```
>>> c = {}
>>> for key in a:
    c[key] = list(set(a[key]) - set(b.get(key,[])))


>>> c
{'joe': [32, 422], 'bob': [24], 'jack': [0, 3, 222]}
```

EDIT - lose the second set:

As Padraic Cunningham mentioned in the comments (as he so often does, bless his soul), you can make use of `set.difference` to avoid explicitly casting your second list to a set:

```
>>> c = {}
>>> for key in a:
    c[key] = list(set(a[key]).difference(b.get(key,[])))


>>> c
{'joe': [32, 422], 'bob': [24], 'jack': [0, 3, 222]}
```

or with list comprehension:

```
>>> {key: list(set(a[key]).difference(b.get(key,[]))) for key in a}
{'joe': [32, 422], 'bob': [24], 'jack': [0, 3, 222]}
```

or if you want to treat `set.difference` as a class method instead of an instance method:

```
>>> {key: list(set.difference(set(a[key]),b.get(key,[]))) for key in a}
{'joe': [32, 422], 'bob': [24], 'jack': [0, 3, 222]}
```

Though I find this a tad bit clunky and I don't really like it as much.

Comment: Perfect! Great answer and thanks again for the explanation

Comment: You don't need to call set twice, you can use `set.difference`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, what do you mean by that? doesnt `set.diference` require sets as arguments?

Comment: @RNar, the second arg can be any iterable, calling set means you first create a set then you check each value, using .diffeence no second set is created. `list(set(a[key]).difference(b.get(key,[]))`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I just tested that out right now, did not know that! thanks for it, will edit

Answer (score 7):

You need to use sets:

```
diff = {}
for key in a:
    diff[key] = list(set(a[key]) - set(b.get(key, [])))
print diff
```

Answer (score 3):

Another way is using built-in method [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter):

```
>>> a = {'joe': [24,32,422], 'bob': [1,42,32,24], 'jack':[0,3,222]}
>>> b = {'joe': [24], 'bob': [1,42,32]}
>>> {key:filter(lambda s: s not in b.get(key,[]), a[key]) for key in a}
{'bob': [24], 'joe': [32, 422], 'jack': [0, 3, 222]}
```

As per [`Padraic Cunningham`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2141635/padraic-cunningham) comments:

In Python 3, `filter` returns a `generator`, so, you'll need to convert it to a list, this way:

`{key:list(filter(lambda s: s not in b.get(key,[]), a[key])) for key in a}`

Comment: You would need `list(filter...` for anyone using python3

Comment: Yes...but OP mentioned it's 2.7

Comment: Yes but others may see the answer ;)

Comment: Thanks @PadraicCunningham .. :)